# order mysql query based on two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

To make my query faster, I `paginate` according to the primary key `id` which is set as the start value, i.e `posts.id > $start`.

This is how I fetch regular posts i.e the `id` is fetched sequentially on the next query request

```html
// start value
$start = $_GET['start'];

if ($start <= 0) {
    // set as first request
    $offSet = "AND posts.id > $start";
}
else if ($start > 0) {
    // set as subsequent request
    $offSet = "AND posts.id < $start";
}

// fetch posts
$posts = $db->query("SELECT posts.id, posts.likes,
                        posts.dislikes, posts.comments
    FROM posts, users
    WHERE posts.user_id=users.id
        $offSet
    ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 0, 15");
```

This is how I fetch most liked posts

```html
// fetch posts
$posts = $db->query("SELECT posts.id, posts.likes,
                        posts.dislikes, posts.comments
    FROM posts, users
    WHERE posts.user_id=users.id
        $offSet
      AND posts.likes != 0
    ORDER BY posts.likes DESC LIMIT 0, 15");
```

The problem is that if I `ORDER BY likes DESC`, the `id` will not be sequential and thus if I request more posts the results will repeat the first set of results.

Could anyone help me write a query that will fetch posts and `ORDER BY posts.likes DESC` and still allow me to paginate the query based on the `id` so that subsequent requests don't gradually become slower (on account of mysql going through all previous rows)

**This is an implementation courtesy of @RickJames**

```html
$start = $leftoff_likes = 0;

// fetch most liked posts
$posts = $db->query("
    SELECT posts.id, posts.body, posts.user_id, posts.tag, posts.date, posts.comments, posts.likes, posts.dislikes, users.name, users.image 
    FROM posts, users 
    WHERE   posts.likes <= $leftoff_likes
      AND ( posts.likes <  $leftoff_likes OR posts.id < $start ) 
      AND posts.user_id=users.id 
    ORDER BY posts.likes DESC, posts.id DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 15");

echo json_encode($posts);
```

Comment: Use INNER JOIN instead of Comma

Comment: How do you mean

Comment: Instead of `FROM a,b WHERE a.x=b.x`, do `FROM a JOIN b ON a.x=b.x`.  They have the same effect; the latter is the "modern" syntax.

Comment: yes thankyou @RickJames it works really well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Efficient compound:**

You need a 2-column `ORDER BY` to get the ordering better.  And that complicates the `WHERE` clause, especially when several items have the same number of Likes.

Starting with most liked:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE   likes <= $leftoff_likes
      AND ( likes <  $leftoff_likes OR id < $leftoff_id ) 
    ORDER BY likes DESC, id DESC
    LIMIT 16
```

Starting with least liked:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE   likes >= $leftoff_likes
      AND ( likes >  $leftoff_likes OR id > $leftoff_id ) 
    ORDER BY likes ASC, id ASC
    LIMIT 16
```

Display the first 15 results on the current page, and set (for next time) $leftoff_likes and $leftoff_id from the 16th item.  Pass those via the URL behind the `[Next]` and `[Prev]` buttons.

`OFFSET` is never used.

Have, if practical, `INDEX(likes, id)`

(That tip was squirreled away in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#iterating_through_a_compound_key )

**Miscellany notes:**

"Remembering where you left off" is better than using `LIMIT` with `OFFSET`.  See:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

That makes for multiple changes.  I recommend writing two complete queries instead of patching with `$offset`.

Comment: thank you, could you explain this a bit further please, using my code above.

Comment: Ah, I skipped something -- `$start` is not sufficient, you also need to remember `$likes`.  Replace $Genus and $species with $likes and $start.

Comment: for me $likes is not a variable, should I substitute with posts.likes? I am having a bit of a hard time corelating them.

Comment: @MaxNjoroge - When finishing with one page, you have two numbers representing where the page "left off" -- the `likes` and `id` of the "last" row fetched for the page.  These come from the `SELECT` into PHP variables, then into the URL for the [Next] or [Prev] button, and back into PHP fur use as $likes and $id for the next page's `SELECT`.  See my pagination blog.  (It recommends fetching 16 rows and remembering the `likes` and `id` of the 16th; this changes '>' to '>=', etc.)

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, I have tried to incorporate it to the code above but still can't figure it out, I'm still getting duplicates. Is it possible for you to edit my code above with your explanation.

Comment: @MaxNjoroge - Are the dups in one page?  Or between two pages?  Are you talking about the query with "likes" or the simpler one (all posts)?  Show me what is giving dups.

Comment: The duplicates are in one page and occur when I request more rows on the same page. When I order by ID they do not occur at all. But when I order by likes/dislikes/comments the duplicates happen when requesting the next 15 rows

Comment: @MaxNjoroge - I rewrote my Answer.

Comment: i added trial implementation to my question. However, it now gives me null results

Comment: Can you take a look at this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ed79fcfb4b479f30b1bac0aa0dde753).  I changed pagina length to 3 because of the amount of test data.   Maybe you can  change/adapt this DBFIDDLE to show the null results ?

Comment: Thank you @RickJames and @Luuk, turns out the @RickJames code works just fine. @Luuk, It wasn't working because my query was nested in `$db->query()` which, with the spacing & new line, was not working. But otherwise, @RickJames code is working just fine. Thank you @Luuk for your fiddle which made me see this!